Relativity explained using sound instead of light
A friend of mine asked me to explain Einstein relativity to him, and I tried to use a methaphore using sound, however for some reason it does’t quite work:

imagine there are 2 people with a clock, and one is constantly spitting out the same frequency of sound. Then, the other person starts moving away for the first (talking) one. This moving person will feel like that the first one is “slowed”, up to a point where if it moves as fast as the sound, the time will freeze.
However, if he slows down, it will go back to the “time frame” (meant as “speed of time) of the other talking person, and if he then goes back towards the initial point, it will feel as the time is moving faster (as the frequency increases due to the doppler effect)

I always though to relativity in this way, by which I mean that if I move away from you, it will slow down time because of  some sort of doppler effect of the light
However, this whole reasoning doesn’t quite work, as during the whole experiment, the clock of the two people are actually absolutely synchronized
So here’s my question, in which “relaxation” of the actual relativity I made I’ve screwed up?

The speed of light is the same for different frames. It is not the case with the speed of sound. It is even possible to fly beyond the speed of sound. So the analogy doesn't work.

Relativity does not explain the Doppler effect and the Doppler effect does not explain Relativity.

@ClaudioSaspinski indeed, however I wanted to use it as a methaphore, implying that it is a sort of doppler effect wrt the light, though it doesn’t work at it never explains time dilation, a thus i was curious on where it wasnt holding as a way of reasoning
